# ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got a library called google-translate-python. https://github.com/terryyin/google-translate-python

Basically, I copied/pasted the `translate.py` file to my python27/lib directory. I imported it like so:

```
from translate import Translator
```

And I put in something like this:

```
theTranslate = Translator(to_lang="sp")
translation = theTranslate.translate("hello")
```

And I'm using pycharm btw so I haven't gotten any errors, it is saying the methods are there and everything.

However, I get the error: `ImportError: cannot import name Translator`

Did I import the library wrong? that's all I can think of. Because the methods are there and running.

Comment: From the github page you linked: **Installation**: `pip install translate`.

Comment: yeah i cant get pip to work at all, i just copied and pasted it, is it not enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out... the library I was trying to import had the same name as my actual python file. So my python file was called translate.py and my library I was trying to import was called translate. I don't know how to differentiate it.. but changing the name of my python file fixed it. wow.. that took about 3 hours to realize.

Comment: I committed the same error with PyDictionary. The python file must be different from the library name!

Answer (score 0):

Does it show in the list of packages installed under Pycharm interpreter? You need to add the package to this list and then it becomes available to you for import. It is available as one of the packages there.

Comment: well i copied it patsed to the python library directory and it is accepting it, it doesnt show a red line or anything. even when i access it, it is finding the class and showing the methods to it, it doesnt make sense why it is giving the error

Comment: Try doing the package installation through the Project Interpreter, I think it has to do with visibility to the methods available in that class

Comment: Goto Settings>Project Interpreter> There you will see the libraries installed....click the + button which will take you to the list of available libraries and just type Translate...this will show you the package and its description. FYI...if using MAC settings is under Preferences

Comment: my library was called the same thing as my python program lol :(

Comment: Im glad you figured it out...it happens:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the github page the package can be installed from the source using:

python setup.py install

Another option is to save the translate.py to the local directory or another directory.

If translate.py is not in the local directory you can add the module path using:

sys.path.append('PATH_TO_TRANSLATE.PY')

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use pip the simplest way to get this installed would be to do download the source code ([.zip file](https://github.com/terryyin/google-translate-python/archive/master.zip)) and unzip it.

Open a terminal (where you have access to python) and change to the folder (`cd <the path to the folder>`) you have unzipped, and then run:

```
python setup.py install
```

This will make sure the files end up in the right location (which on Windows is actually in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`).

Comment: @simon Do you have a file named "translate.py" in the same folder you are running your script? ie. is one of the files you've created named that.

Comment: You can do `import translate; print translate.__file__` to see which file is being imported.

Comment: yes htat was the problem.. i figured it out earlier right before yo usaid that... same file name as library

Comment: @simon It happens to us all don't worry ;)