# Python translate module not working in script

Tags: python, translate, python-idle

I am having an issue with running the module "translate" using a script.

```
from translate import Translator
import requests
translator = Translator(from_lang = "zh", to_lang="en")

translation = translator.translate("""猗與那與、置我鞉鼓。
奏鼓簡簡、衎我烈祖。
湯孫奏假、綏我思成。
鞉鼓淵淵、嘒嘒管聲。
既和且平、依我磬聲。
於赫湯孫、穆穆厥聲。
庸鼓有斁、萬舞有奕。
我有嘉客、亦不夷懌。
自古在昔、先民有作。
溫恭朝夕、執事有恪。
顧予烝嘗、湯孫之將""")

print(translation)
```

The strange thing is that the script runs if I copy the code line by line into IDLE. However, if I were to run the script, I get the following message

ImportError: cannot import name 'Translator'

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580749/importerror-cannot-import-name

Comment: by "if I were to run the script" do you mean running from IDLE or somewhere else like in cmd typing python filename.py ?

Comment: Did you name your script itself, or some other script in the same directory `translate.py`?

Comment: if @kaanbobac answer doesn't works for you, you might have 2 or more python versions try to running it by giving full path of your python

Answer (score 3):

What's the name of the file that contains your code? If it's the same as the library you're trying to import (i.e. `translate`) then python will throw this error since python cannot differentiate between the file and the library names.

Comment: Yes, I saved the script with the same name. Thanks.